# Can't emulate Android IONIC CORDOVA

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-studio, gradle

I try to install Ionic and test to emulate the "todo" project. All is okay but when I run :

```
ionic cordova emulate android
```

I have an error with gradle :

> Android Studio project detected Running command:
>
> /home/nathan/todo/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>
> /home/nathan/todo ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
>
> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle studio Starting a Gradle Daemon
>   (subsequent builds will be faster)
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example,
>     an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide
>     chapter on the daemon at
>     https://docs.gradle.org/4.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Please read
>
>   ### the following process output to find out more:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

Here is what java -version show me :

> java version "1.8.0_171"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>
> 1.8.0_171-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

Did you have an idea ? I run Ubuntu 18.10. Install Android studio from APT and also install Gradle from APT. I try to modify the gradle.properties on the todo project (`node_modules/cordova-android/spec/fixtures/android_studio_project/gradle.properties`) with (after some research on forums) :

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
>
> org.gradle.daemon=true

Comment: go into platform/android folder and run `./gradlew clean`, it may help :D.

Comment: I didn't have the <code>gradlew</code> scripts into the Ionic project platform/android folder. Is that normal ?

Comment: have you installed android sdk too?

Comment: Android Studio doesn't install Android SDK ?